# Sublime Text Python3.6 cmd+shift+b not working

Tags: python, macos, sublimetext

I've set up a new build system for Sublime Text (Python 3.6).

The problem is that the build system does not show up results.
Python 2.7 works properly.
The cmd+Shift+B command is not working either (Python 3.6).

```
"cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"encoding": "unicode",
"path": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/"
```

}

The way the new build system is set-up.

Comment: which sublime config file/option is this from?

Comment: it's the python3.6.sublime-build

Comment: okay, solved it by changing unicode to ascii (which is still bad).

Comment: Hmm that seems odd, since python 3 is meant to handle unicode well. But maybe the unicode is just for the build process itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],
```

Or if you don't have python3 there, just use whatever you get from typing this in command line:

```
$ which python3
```

Note that when I did this, it broke my Python build (2.7) so I had to change `cmd` to reflect the full path to the python binary.

Comment: still no output :/